# Sketching the graph of $\cos(4\pi t-\pi)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I am struggling to sketch the graph of $\cos(4\pi t-\pi), -3<t<3$. Here is what I have tried:
$w=4\pi$
$f=2$
$T=0.5$

So the graph will start from $0$, and form two cycles between $0$ and $1$, two cycles between $1$ and $2$, and so on. But I am missing out on the shift of $\pi$ to the right. Could someone please help me visualize and sketch this graph? Thanks

Comment: The $-\pi $ will shift the curve $\pi $ units to the right (for $t=0$ you have $\cos \left ( -\pi \right) =-1$).

Comment: Keep in mind that after shifting $\pi$ units to the right, that the shift is then compressed by a factor of $4\pi$. That is why it's better to express the function as $$\cos(4\pi (t - \frac{1}{4}))$$. That way, the horizontal compression occurs before the right shift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you go about making any statements about the horizontal shift, first put the function in horizontal shift form:

$$c_0f(x-c_1)+c_2$$

Here the $f$ is a "parent function" and the horizontal shift is $c_1$ right assuming $c_1>0$

Your function is:

$\cos(4\pi(t-\frac{1}{4}))$

We can take the the "parent function" to be $f(t)=\cos(4\pi t)$.

So the horizontal shift is $\frac{1}{4}$ to the right.

Graph $\cos(4\pi t)$ like you usually would with domain all real numbers. Shift all points to the right by a fourth . And finally then, worry about your domain of interest $t \in (-3,3)$ and erase any points outside this interval.

Here is a portion of the graph with $\cos(4\pi t)$ in red and $\cos(4\pi t-\pi)$ in blue.

[image]